# Personalize page content with data passed through a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a page for digital campaigns and I'd like to personalize the content of that page based on who referred users there.

For example, A sends B a link to this page, I generate the link to be sent by A automatically on his dashboard. When B clicks the link, I want the page title to say "Hey, A referred you here"

I know the solution to this might be simple but I'm not very awesome with web dev yet. How do I

1. Pass this information through the link?
2. Collect the information on the page and put it in as part of the content?

Looking forward to suggestions for most effective implementation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters

Comment: Use a `GET` parameter that contains a code unique to each person, and run code inside a conditional based on that parameter. How you decipher and display that unique parameter is up to you, but you'll likely want to do this **server-side** (in order to compare against a database).

Answer (score 1):

## Theory

You can pass information to a page through the URL using URL parameters. This method of posting data is called `GET`

For example, take this URL:

```
example.com?key1=val1&key2=val2
```

You can send any number of parameters using the syntax `key=value` (note, value is not enclosed in quotes), and separate each one with an `&`. You must put a question mark between the URL and the parameters.

### JavaScript

You can then retrieve the URL parameters using the following JavaScript code. Insert the following at the beginning of your page.

```
//To get Query Strings with JS 
var urlParams; 
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
    pl = /\+/g, // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
    search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
    decode = function (s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " "));
    },
    query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
        urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();
```

To get the value of a URL parameter, do the following:

```
var x = urlParams.key1; // x will be "val1"
```

### PHP

To retrieve the URL parameters using PHP, it is much simpler. You don't need to add any code to the beginning of the page as with JavaScript, as it is an inbuilt feature of PHP. Just do the following:

```
$x = $_GET["key1"]; // $x will be "val1"
```

## Practice

In your case, you could make the URL show for user Albert, his unique URL for sharing could be

```
example.com?sender=Albert
```

And on your website you could put

```
<script>
    if (urlParams.hasOwnProperty("sender")) {
        document.write("Hey, " + urlParams.sender + " reffered you here!");
    }
</script>
```